# GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /path_name/bin/gfortran)

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

I already have GCC and Gfortran installed. It is gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52). However, I am trying to install a more recent gfortran compiler. Here is what I did so far. From the http://gfortran.meteodat.ch/download/x86_64/  I downloaded the nightly "gcc-trunk.tar.xz" and I extracted it into the directory "opt." This created the directory "gcc-trunk". I then downloaded the "gcc-5-infrastructure.tar.xz" and extracted it into "gcc-trunk." I then input

> PATH="$HOME/gcc-trunk/bin":$PATH
>
> MANPATH="$HOME/gcc-trunk/share/man"
>
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/gcc-trunk/lib64":"$HOME/gcc-trunk/lib":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

on bash. I then tried to verify whether gfortran installed correctly with

> /path_name/gfortran -v

However, I get the message GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /path_name/bin/gfortran). I am not sure what is the problem. What should I do?

Comment: The ldd vesion is:
ldd (GNU libc) 2.5

Comment: Well RHEL 4 is **really** old. This complicates things quite a lot...

Comment: @Alexandrer Vogt Ok it looks that I do not know enough. I thought I could install something with Wikipedia knowledge. What are some references that I could look to get a general idea on installing and running programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gfortran binary you downloaded was built against a newer version of glibc than the one you have installed on your system.

You can solve this problem e.g. by

- Acquiring a gfortran binary built against an older version of glibc
- Building GCC from source
- Upgrade to a newer distro with a newer glibc

Comment: Here is a short guide on how to compile `gfortran`: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranSource. Which such an old OS, it might be difficult though to get all the dependencies right.